# Sequelize - Change Watcher (one database, two different apps)

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have two different Node Projects that access to the same database with sequelize.

One of the Node Apps (kind of backoffice) updates some tables and the other one use the data of that tables to performs some operation.

The thing is that this data should not be changed constantly and the second app need to be as fast as possible, thats why the second app querys the tables once (when app starts) and then stores this data in memory so it can do the operations faster (because the are no i/o to database).

My problem is that sometimes, this data may change throw the first app, and as this two apps have no contact between them (for security reasons) the only way I see is to have some "dirty" flag in some table of the database, and then make the first app to change it after some update and the second app to query each X seconds in order to check if this flag has been changed.

I don't like this approach and that's why I'm posting this question:

**Does Sequelize provides a better or fancy way to do this ?**
like some kind of "changes/dirty" watcher

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use something fast in between them like a redis cache?

Comment: Hi, thanks. As I see it this won't help me too much because I will have to update the cache manually since redis won't do the trick of auto fetching when db values have changed

Comment: Update Redis when you update the db values...

Comment: yep but the app that updates the database is running in another pc.